# Error al cambiar la version de compilador en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

estoy trabajando en una aplicacion en android studio, cuando quiero cambiar la version de compilador al 26 me da el siguiente error:

> 5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not
>   found.

con un link que me manda a los siguientes codigo:

```
<resources>
<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat"/>
<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
<style name="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- We can use the platform styles on API 28+ -->
    <item name="dialogCornerRadius">?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius</item>
</style>
<style name="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- We can use the platform styles on API 28+ -->
    <item name="dialogCornerRadius">?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius</item>
</style>
```

codigo de mi archivo app:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ocr"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

dependencias:

```
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    //image crop library
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'

    //image to text google library
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:19.0.0'

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El elemento al cual se hace referencia y que no se encuentra, debe estar disponible desde la API 27

> 5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not
>   found.

Para solucionar este detalle, debes cambiar como minimo a la versión 27 de :

```
 compileSdkVersion ?
 buildToolsVersion ?
 targetSdkVersion ?
```

Puedes realizarlo desde tu proyecto y selecciona `Open Module Settings` ( <kbd>F4</kbd> )

ahí puedes cambiar en "Properties" tu Compile Sdk Version y Build Tools Version, en "Default Config" cambia tu Target SDK Version:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También puedes realizarlo desde tu archivo `build.gradle`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]